# MathML in Android

Tags: java, android, math, mathml

I am aware about Android webkit doesn't support MathML. but I am working on on Maths related project and my client has send some thousands of MathML files.

I have tried with "MathJax" it works but its Internet based and rending speed is very slow, it takes around 2 to 3 sec to render file, I also tired to implement locally but it requires lot of resources and he is not able to find some resources from local folders.

Is there any way to display MathML in Android? if not then what would be best approach if I already have thousands of MathML files.

Comment: what did you end up doing. I have same need. thx

Comment: You can use a not-so-pretty alternative, jqMath: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127355/using-jqmath-in-android-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [JEuclid](http://jeuclid.sourceforge.net/)

It does nice job taking MathML and creating a JPG, PNG, etc. It will also display the equations in a GUI (and I'm guessing you can look at the GUI code and incorporate that into your own project)

Comment: JEuclid requires java.awt.image.* which is not available in Android

Answer (score 1):

Firefox on android supports mathml natively

Comment: I am thinking to use firefox WebView programmatically instead of Android WebView, searched in this direction but didn't find much help, any idea about this ?