# Using jqMath in Android application

Tags: android, webview, jqmath

I'am newbie in Android programming and I want to us jqMath to display some math formulas in WebView.

Here is my code:

```
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
String js = "<html><head>"
    + "<link rel='stylesheet' href='jqmath-0.4.0.css'>"
    + "<script src='jquery-1.4.3.min.js'></script>"
    + "<script src='jqmath-etc-0.4.0.min.js'></script>"
    + "</head><body>"
    + "<script>var s = '$ax^2+bx+c=0$ with $a≠0$';M.parseMath(s);document.write(s);</script></body>";
webView.loadData(js,  "text/html",  "UTF-8");
```

What is the problem of this code?,

**UPDATE**
well my problem have solved, but I also changed loadData function to loadDataWithBaseURL 
I mention just for reference if anyone else have same problem

Comment: This use of M.parseMath(s) is incorrect, and is being copied to other stackoverflow pages/questions. M.parseMath() should be passed a DOM node, not a string, and is only necessary if you need to change mathematics after the page is fully loaded, e.g. due to user interaction. The call here is a no-op. For anyone copying this code, get rid of the <script> tag, variable s, M.parseMath(s) call, and document.write(s). Change that whole line to + "$ax^2+bx+c=0$ with $a≠0$</body>";

Comment: Also the js variable is really html, not js.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the path correctly for the css,js files as following:

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
String path="file:///android_asset/";
String js = "<html><head>"
+ "<link rel='stylesheet' href='"+path+"jqmath-0.4.0.css'>"
+ "<script src='"+path+"jquery-1.4.3.min.js'></script>"
+ "<script src='"+path+"jqmath-etc-0.4.0.min.js'></script>"
+ "</head><body>"
+ "<script>var s = '$ax^2+bx+c=0$ with $a≠0$';M.parseMath(s);document.write(s);</script></body>";
webView.loadData(js,  "text/html",  "UTF-8");
```

note that the files should be in assets folder.

Comment: I too faced a similar issue. The path can't be short. Without path, rest of the code works, but fails to load the .js file, and fails to render the formula.

Answer (score 1):

the location of js lib in assets folder does not match your src declaration assuming that you placed the js libs in assets/js

Answer (score 0):

After specifying the path like [Khalid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1475574/khalid-taha) said, the following worked for me

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL( "file:///android_asset/" ,js,  "text/html",  "UTF-8", null);
```

instead of `webView.loadData` method.