# How to use jqMath in Android Studio

Tags: android, jqmath

I'm a beginner in Android. I want to display Mathematical and Science Formula. 
I have heard abt the jqMath, I did lots of search on it. But I couldn't find out how to use it actually. So Please help me out to use it.. Its basic Steps n all..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you want?

[Using jqMath in Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127355/using-jqmath-in-android-application)

Or here:
https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?q=jqmath%20android%20example

Comment: @Alexksandr Ostaf  Thankx.. what do we need  to paste in assets file.??